# Find the sequence, given generating function: $ f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am obliged to find the sequence which generating function is $\large f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$. I know how to find a sequence for example for $\large f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}$ I show it as two fractions and then it comes the easy part. But for this I am stuck, because i cannot show it as sum of two fraction. I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$(1+t)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}t^k$$
for $t=x/2$ and $n=2$ we get
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}=(x+2)^{-2}=(2(1+(x/2))^{-2}=$$
$$=2^{-2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\binom{2+k-1}{k}(x/2)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k2^{-2-k}\binom{k+1}{k}x^k$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(k+1)2^{-2-k}x^k=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}x^k$$

Comment: Thank you , I think I may understand this. But what heppens if I have $\large f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}$ Is there a formula for this too ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}=-2^{-2}(1+(-x/2))^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots \\
\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1+2z+3z^2 + \cdots
$$

Let $z(x) = -x-1$, so that $x = -z-1$.  After substituting, you'll find
$$
f(x) =  \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = 1+2z+3z^2 + \cdots = 
1 + 2(-x-1) + 3(-x-1)^2 + \cdots
$$

Comment: So my what will be formula for my sequence (e.g $a_n=....$) ? How to count this? I understand that you do this substitution because sequence for generating function $f(x) =  \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ is well known ?